# ¿Como puedo alinear el texto frente al icono como en la imagen?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

necesito alinear la imagen como se muestra ya que tal cual lo tengo se muestra en la parte de arriba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <div class="row ">
      <img class="icono-whats" src="assets/img/iconos/whatsapp.png" alt="whats app">
      <span>+527225572870</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase row de Bootstrap ya hace **flex** al elemento que se le aplica, para alinear verticalmente se puede utilizar la clase `align-items-center`, luego al **span** agregar una clase `ml-3` o el tamaño que necesites para la separación.
De todos modos cuando se utiliza la clase **row**, siempre se utiliza dentro al menos 2 **col**.
De otra manera solo es un **div**, en cuyo caso se puede hacer lo siguiente, agrego ambos casos...

**Como lo tienes actualmente:**

```
 <div class="row align-items-center">
      <img class="icono-whats" src="assets/img/iconos/whatsapp.png" alt="whats app">
      <span class="ml-3">+527225572870</span>
 </div>
```

**Sin la clase "row":**

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <img src="assets/img/iconos/whatsapp.png" width="80px" alt="whats app" />
  <span class="ml-4">+527225572870</span>
</div>
```

Eso es basado en que tu pregunta indica que estás utilizando Bootstrap 4, en caso de utilizar una versión más reciente, el **ml**(margin-left) se reemplaza por **ms**(margin-start).

Comment: No estoy seguro la verdad de si las normas del sitio permiten pasar datos de contacto, pero entro a diario y si veo alguna pregunta en la que pueda ayudarte, siempre será un placer, te recomiendo en las preguntas ser lo más específico posible, que problema tenés, que resultado esperás tener, como es tu código actual, que cosas has probado, donde estás trancado. Si haces preguntas que no respeten esos puntos, puede que te las cierren o voten negativo. Quedo a las órdenes.